# Как сделать изменение цвета под кнопкой в xml?

Tags: android, xml

Как сделать изменение цвета под кнопкой background-ом? Вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Цвета не ваши. Уж извините)

```
<!--Нижний фон - разделен на части с помощью весов 3 и 7 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="BUTTON"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     />

<!--Линия привязки на высоте 30%-->
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3"/>
```